# Delete Locking Insert In same transaction?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Suppose you have a explicit transaction that deletes data from TableA first and then inserts data into that table:

```
BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE...

INSERT INTO TableA
SELECT...

COMMIT TRAN
```

Is it possible that DELETE operation acquires exclusive lock (X) due to lock escalation on TableA, does not realease lock after finishing deleting, because transaction is not yet finished and insert can't proceed and just waits endlessly bacause TableA is locked?

Comment: A session can't deadlock with itself. Also even if you run this concurrently with multiple sessions, as both operations happen against the same table then you shouldn't encounter deadlocks. Deadlocks happen when a session is waiting for a resource while holding a lock than another session wants and the other is also holding the resource we want. For this to happen, the resources should be different, as if they were the same the request for the lock gets queued.

Comment: More importantly - why are you asking?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar situation when delete succeeds, right after delete i log that lock for tableA becomes X and insert just hangs there for hours. Same insert takes 30sec while running independently in another session.

Comment: @EzLo googl: sql server self deadlock

Comment: While the table is locked, you should be able to see which SPID is locking it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that DELETE operation acquires exclusive lock (X) due
>   to lock escalation on TableA, does not realease lock after finishing
>   deleting, because transaction is not yet finished and insert can't
>   proceed and just waits endlessly bacause TableA is locked?

If we don't discuss recources like `exchangeEvent` and `threadpool`, but only `key`/`rid`/`page`/`table`/`database` resources, there are `sessions`/`transactions` to acquire locks, not `operations`.

If you look at the `dmv` `sys.dm_tran_locks` you'll see not "operation" but `request_session_id` defined as `Session ID` that currently owns this request.

Once you understand this you'll be able to respond yourself.

Your session acquired `X-lock` on the table, for further modification **this same session** needs `X-lock` (may be more granular but still `X-lock`), but it's already acquired. There is no any conflict and no `lock` need to be acquired.

You can prove it to yourself by executing a code like this one:

```
select top 1000 n, 
                replicate('a',100) as filler
into dbo.a
from nums.dbo.nums;

BEGIN TRAN

DELETE FROM dbo.a with(tablock)
WHERE n = 10;

select *
from sys.dm_tran_locks
where resource_type <> 'DATABASE'
and request_session_id = @@spid;

dbcc traceon(3604, 1200, -1);
INSERT INTO dbo.a
SELECT top 2 n, 
                replicate('a',100) as filler
from nums.dbo.nums;
dbcc traceoff(3604, 1200, -1);

COMMIT TRAN
```

Here I first create my test table by doing `select into` from `Nums` table, then I delete from it with `tablock` that locked the whole table with `X-lock` and check if it was locked, finally I used trace flags `3604`, `1200` to print out all the `locks` acquired while doing `insert`, here they are:

```
Process 60 acquiring IS lock on OBJECT: 11:565577053:0  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 60 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 11:1:5088  (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 60 acquiring S lock on KEY: 11:72057594039173120 (1b7fe5b8af93) (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 60 releasing lock on KEY: 11:72057594039173120 (1b7fe5b8af93)

Process 60 acquiring S lock on KEY: 11:72057594039173120 (f03d7d8b0dcc) (class bit0 ref1) result: OK

Process 60 releasing lock on KEY: 11:72057594039173120 (f03d7d8b0dcc)

Process 60 releasing lock on OBJECT: 11:565577053:0
```

My test db_id is `24`, `11` is db_id of database where table `Nums` resides, as you can see no additional `lock` was acquired in database where I did my `insert`. This is because `X-lock` is already acquired on the `table`.